# Best Computer Monitor under 150$

Tags: pc, monitors, hdmi

I am planning to buy a monitor, I wish to connect it with my laptop ( as a second screen). I searched the internet and couldn't find any decent monitor which fulfills my requirements. I will be mounting it on a stand or on a wall so it should be less heavy and small. Below are my requirements, any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

```
Requirements:

Size       = 18 - 20 inch
Resolution = 1920*1080 (Full HD)
Port       = HDMI (must)
Price      = around 150$
Weight     = light weight
Speaker    = Not an issue
```

Comment: I am assuming you also want the VESA mounts on the monitor? Do you care about the display technology (TN, IPS, etc)? Anything else to help narrow down a selection?

Comment: @Cfinley Anything which offers good picture quality would work fine. I am not looking for any gaming monitor, Mostly I will be reading PDFs, browsing the web and doing some programming.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no one makes a monitor that small with HDMI. Would DVI be fine? You can buy cheap passive converters for a few dollars.

Comment: How about Benq GW2270HM